# Canonical way to install modules and app onto offline system

Tags: python, installation, twisted

We have an app (a bunch of Twisted classes actually) which runs on a specific Python version and depends on quite a bit of modules.  This app needs to be deployed onto a Windows Server machine which has no access to Internet.

Currently we are choosing between:

- having to install Python prior to everything else, and a Python script which unpacks all modules and runs `setup.py`,
- making an NSIS installer which installs Python, then all modules with .exe installers, then unpacks smaller modules into some other dir, then adds the dir to `%PYTHONPATH%`.

What is the good accepted way of dealing with such situation?  Obviously we cannot use `pip`, `easy_install.exe` and other blessed tools, and our approaches are silly and inelegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a third option you can consider deploing the application as an executable using PyInstaller (http://www.pyinstaller.org). You dont need to install anything on the client machine (not even python)

> PyInstaller is a program that converts (packages) Python programs into stand-alone executables, under Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, Solaris and AIX. Its main advantages over similar tools are that PyInstaller works with any version of Python since 2.4, it builds smaller executables thanks to transparent compression, it is fully multi-platform, and use the OS support to load the dynamic libraries, thus ensuring full compatibility.

I have used it in a project to deploy standalone application in both Linux and Windows. Worked like a charm. My project also used Twisted.

Between your current two choices the setup.py approach is more pythonic. But beware that if any of your modules has some c implementation for faster performance that need to be compiled, you can't do that on you client's machine.

Comment: Much as I like the technology involved in wheels, using something like `pyinstaller` means that you don't have to invoke the (finicky, error prone, not-maintained-by-you) logic in distutils or setuptools on a remote, disconnected machine where it might fail in interesting or novel ways.  If it's self-contained, then the only code you have to worry about running is your application (and of course python, and whatever bootstrap code that pyinstaller has - but you probably have to deal with the former anyway and the latter can be tested pretty easily).

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [wheels](http://wheel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It designed to cover your case, i.e. you build wheel once, downloading all required packages. Then you just copy wheel archive to the target machine and install your application without downloading anything.

Comment: Thank you!  Will I need to bring any additional modules to the target machine before I can install the wheel package?  I. e. can it generate "self-extracting" packets which only require minimal Python environment as provided by the default Python installation?

Comment: You should have pip and wheel packages for unpacking wheel archive, and optionally virtualenv. See [usage section](http://wheel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#usage) of wheel docs, there is a pretty simple and clear example.